# How to update a list which is passed 3 times from a single page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am on page 1, where I am getting a list through api. This page has a `TabBar` with 3 tabs in it which displays some lists through `ListRenderer` widget. I have to filter the data and show accordingly on the 3 different tabs. I am first filtering the list accordingly and then passing them to the respective `ListRenderer` widgets.

Now, in that list renderer, I am making a list of `VideoUploadingTile` and displaying it through `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column` (I can't use listview due to some reasons). Now, in `VideoUploadingTile`, I am making an api call and through that, I am making changes to the tiles. Now, that change is only displayed on the respective `ListRenderer` widget, not on the other twos.

For example, I received a list of 20, and is divided into 3 parts of 20,5, and 15, where first `ListRenderer` will show all items of list. Now, I am changing a property of an item which is present in 2nd list as well. So, if changes are displayed on 1st list, that same item on 2nd list will be unchanged. I want that to change accordingly to the first list and vice versa. How can i do that??

1st page:

```
                  ListRenderer(
                    participants: widget.activity.groups![0].enParticipations, 
                    rid: widget.activity.id.toString(),
                    activity: widget.activity,
                    notificationCountData: notificationCountResult?.countData??[],
                    function: (val) {
                      if(val==1) {
                        getNotificationCount();
                        startTimer();
                      }
                      else if(val==2) {
                        timer?.cancel();
                      }
                    },
                    isUploading: (val) {
                      isLoading=val;
                      debugPrint('In all activity: $val');
                    },
                ),
                ListRenderer(
                    rid: widget.activity.id.toString(),
                    participants: widget.activity.groups![0].enParticipations == null
                        ? []
                        : widget.activity.groups![0].enParticipations!
                            .where(
                                (element) => element.state == GRADED || element.state==READY_TO_GRADE)  //"<-this"
                            .toList(),
                    activity: widget.activity,
                    notificationCountData: notificationCountResult?.countData??[],
                    function: (val) {
                      if(val==1) {
                        getNotificationCount();
                        startTimer();
                      }
                      else if(val==2) {
                        timer?.cancel();
                      }
                    },
                    isUploading: (val) {
                      debugPrint('In all activity: $val');
                    },
                ),
                ListRenderer(
                    rid: widget.activity.id.toString(),
                    participants: widget.activity.groups![0].enParticipations == null
                        ? []
                        : widget.activity.groups![0].enParticipations!
                            .where(
                                (element) => element.state == YET_TO_SUBMIT)  //"<-this"
                            .toList(),
                    activity: widget.activity,
                    notificationCountData: notificationCountResult?.countData??[],
                    function: (val) {
                      if(val==1) {
                        getNotificationCount();
                        startTimer();
                      }
                      else if(val==2) {
                        timer?.cancel();
                      }
                    },
                    isUploading: (val) {
                      debugPrint('In all activity: $val');
                    },
                ),
```

ListRenderer:

```
class ListRenderer extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListRenderer({
    super.key,
    this.participants,
    required this.rid,
    required this.activity,
    required this.notificationCountData,
    required this.function,
    required this.isUploading,
  });

  final List<EnParticipation>? participants;
  final String rid;
  final GetActivityResult activity;
  final List<StudentWiseCountData> notificationCountData;
  final Function(int) function;
  final Function(bool) isUploading;

  //List<CardUser>? list;

  @override
  State<ListRenderer> createState() => _ListRendererState();
}

class _ListRendererState extends State<ListRenderer> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  List<VideoUploadingTile> list = [];
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  initialize() async {
    await fillList();
  }

  fillList() async {
    int len=widget.participants?.length??0;
    for(int index=0;index<len;index++) {
      var temp = VideoUploadingTile(
        key: ValueKey(widget.participants![index].userId),
        rid: widget.activity.id.toString(),
        data: widget.participants![index],
        activity: widget.activity,
        function: (val) {
          widget.function(val);
        },
        isUploading: (val) {
          widget.isUploading(val);
          debugPrint('The value is: $val');
        },
      );
      list.add(temp);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   debugPrint('List renderer is rebuilding');
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: list,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

And on VideoUploadingTile, I am displaying progress on an api call, which is only displyed on 1st list, not on 2nd and vice versa. Also, after that api call, the item should move to third list and get erased from 2nd list, as it's `state` property is changing from graded to yet_to_submit as you can see at the two "<-this" in code. How can I do that?

PS: I can't change state of whole list, because if any other api call is made in any other item, it's ui might get reset if this happens.